# I can't ping my Centos7 VM

Tags: networking, centos, firewall, hyper-v

The VM is Centos7 minimal install.
The hypervisor is Hyper-V on Windows 10.

I can ping google from the VM. I can ping the host from the VM. I can ping other nodes in the subnet from the VM. 
I cannot ping (or SSH) into the VM from anywhere :(

I have disabled firewalld on the VM.

I am probably missing something very small and will kick myself once it's figured out.
Please help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
What solved the thing for me was after I installed Hyper-V-tools for CentOS with following command:

```
sudo yum install -y hyperv-daemons
```

There is a good guide about running CentOS on Hyper-V here: http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/centos-linux-hyper-v/

Hope this information can be good for others as well.